# Testing how JavaScript object works with a simple HTML but it isn't working on browser

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. I was practising on objects and wrote this very short simple code but it isn't working when I run it on browser. I've been racking my brain on what I did wrong here. Here's the part of the HTML code.

Since it's a short code, I inserted the JavaScript code inside the HTML file.

```html
<div>
    This is a bet site called <span id="betname"></span> <br /> 
    Number of available games: <span id="available"></span>
</div>

<script type="javascript">
var = details {
    name: 'betwin.',
    game: 20,
    played: 10,
    checkAvailability: function(){
     return this.game - this.played;
    }
};

var elName = document.getElementById('betname');
elName.textContent = details.name;

var elFigure = document.getElementById('available');
elFigure.textContent = details.checkAvailability();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have defined var details wrong, use `var details = {` instead of `var = details {`. Also give type of script correctly, use `<script type="text/javascript">`

```html
<div>
    This is a bet site called <span id="betname"></span> <br /> 
    Number of available games: <span id="available"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var details = {
    name: 'betwin.',
    game: 20,
    played: 10,
    checkAvailability: function(){
     return this.game - this.played;
    }
};

var elName = document.getElementById('betname');
elName.textContent = details.name;

var elFigure = document.getElementById('available');
elFigure.textContent = details.checkAvailability();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. That was my error. When I run the snippet here, it works. It is still not working on my browser though even after correcting it. I guess I will have to check again if i made any error.

Comment: oh, I forgot the 'text/'. It's working now on my browser. Little errors just took so much of my time. Thanks a lot. I can continue reading in peace

Comment: oh okay definitely. I just joined stackover now. So, still figuring out stuffs about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're close but you've defined your variable wrong. You want to put `details` on the LEFT side of the `=`.

`var details = {...`

Comment: Wow, now i feel so dumb. I have been killing myself for hours now. I appreciate the help